# Copy data from backup table column to original table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I accidentally updated all records for `table2` data column `custno` with `value ='33'`

Now I need to recover all the column data for `custno` from `table1` to `table2` (without affecting the other data).

**Note** that there are no primary keys on either of the tables. It also seems several `ID`s are repeating. 
`table1` may have the same `ID` more than once, and all `ID`s need to be populated with the same date value as found in `table2` for the same `ID`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

> -------------------so here is the actual scenario updated :-------------------------

table 1   (previous table in good state)

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4    colN    custno
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   12
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   12
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   12
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   11
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   11
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   10
```

table 2 ( accidently updated the custno =33 for all the records )

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4    colN    custno
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   33
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   33
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   33
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   33
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   33
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   33
```

now i have to recover this table 2 column (`custno`) exactly as `table1`  without touching any other columns.

I hope this will clear the scenario now.

After updating this query , it gives unexpected result.

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.custno = t1.custno
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
AND t1.col1 =t2.col1 
AND t1.col2 =t2.col2 
AND t1.col3 =t2.col3 
AND t1.colN =t2.colN
```

The unexpected result being

```
id  col1    col2    col3    col4    colN    custno
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   12
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   12
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   12
1   1   dhruv   joshi   3   2   12
1   1   alpha   beta    3   2   12
1   1   ebta    alpha   3   2   12
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have any unique column in the table, you have to apply on condition on multiple columns (of the table) so that it makes the row uniquely identifiable for update.

Example if your table is defined as `table1[ id int, col1 int, col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 int,..., colN int, customerNo int)` and there is no unique column.

Then to update it on basis of customerNo only will pose problems.

The way is to identify multiple(or all) columns to make it more unique during update like this.

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.custno = t1.custno
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
AND t1.col1 =t2.col1 
AND t1.col2 =t2.col2 
AND t1.col3 =t2.col3 
..
AND t1.colN =t2.colN
```

Fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff9895/2
**PS:** This was intended to be a comment to question but because it is too big, I am putting it as answer

I was also wondering if you had a back of the table why don't you simply restore it into original table like

```
-- This deletes all rows
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE Id  IS NOT NULL

-- This inserts all rows from table1(the original table) into table2 to make it like table1
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Comment: the multipart identifier t1.custno= t2.custno could not be bound...this error occur..

Comment: Argh! that was a simple mistake ... updating answer and also adding a Sqlfiddle

Comment: thanks dhruv ..but my scenario is different..I accidently update the all cust no with value 12... so i need to recover that particular column from the originial backup table

Comment: look t1 and t2 contains exactly the same data but accidetly i update custno of t1 with the value 12 for all the records..now i have to recover all the custno from t2  thats the scenario..dhruv

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about but if tables are same structure you can try this:-

```
Update t2 set t2.custno = t1.custno
from
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1 asc)as RANK, * from table_1
)t1
Inner join
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by col1 asc)as RANK, * from table_2
)t2
on t1.RANK = t2.RANK
```